# Iterate over a changing SortedDictionary

Tags: vb.net, sorteddictionary

Utility code I do not have access to is adding rows to the SortedDictionary(of Integer, RowData) I am trying to iterate over. It is adding new RowData's to the end of the list.

So I think the proper solution is to make a copy of the SortedDictionary, and then loop over it. I don't have to worry about sync problems because the new additions are always after the end.

But how to do this? I can't figure out the syntax, the documentation at MS is, hmmm, "basic", and the API doesn't make any sense whatsoever to me. What I want is a copy of the SortedDictionary making another SortedDictionary. But what I get is some sort of KeyValuePair array that I can't seem to make head nor tails of.

```
Dim TempR as KeyValuePair(Of Integer, RowData)
pRowDatas.CopyTo(TempR, 0)
```

That one tells me it can't copy it because one or the other is a 1-dimensional array and the other isn't. So I tried

```
Dim TempR() as KeyValuePair(Of Integer, RowData)
pRowDatas.CopyTo(TempR, 0)
```

And then it complained TempR was null. But you can't New it, or at least I can't.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What do you need to do? It is a common misconception to ask about the approach you took, rather than the original problem you had. Please describe your problem in a short and concise English sentence (10-15 words). Separate your question into two parts - the problem, and steps you have tried. Do not mix them together, because it only adds confusion. If applicable, add a real world scenario. Abstract ideas/examples rarely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code, you need to initialize the array to the size of `pRowDatas`:

```
Dim TempR(0 To pRowDatas.Count-1) As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, RowData)
pRowDatas.CopyTo(TempR, 0)
```

There's also a `ToArray` extension method that you could use:

```
Dim TempR As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, RowData) = pRowDatas.ToArray()
```

Neither of these are inherently thread-safe. The proper way to do this would be to implement a lock both here and in the utility code. Since you have no access to the code, it seems your options are limited here, but someone else may have some idea.